# « Le Renard dit au Loup : Notre cher [...] » : pourquoi ?

Tags: adjectifs, pluriel, littérature, possessif

> [...]
>  Le Renard dit au Loup : **Notre cher**, pour tous mets
>   J'ai souvent un vieux Coq, ou de maigres Poulets ;
>  C'est une
>   viande qui me lasse.
>   Tu fais meilleure chère avec moins de
>   hasard.
>  [...]
>  [ [*Le Loup et le Renard*](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/lourena.htm), (Livre XII, fable 9) Jean de La Fontaine ]

Peut-on expliquer pourquoi l'adjectif possessif de la première personne du pluriel ([*nous*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/notre)) est employé par le renard<sup>1</sup> ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On se rappellera qu'un autre [renard](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/corbrena.htm) s'est déjà adressé à un corbeau en ces termes, après lui avoir ravi son fromage : « *[...] Mon bon Monsieur*, / Apprenez que tout flatteur / Vit aux dépens de celui qui l'écoute. / Cette leçon vaut bien un fromage sans doute. ». Ce renard-là a employé l'adjectif possessif au singulier.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Une autre<sup>1</sup> interprétation que le *nous de majesté*, considérant que le thème de la fable est :

> Certain Renard voulut, dit-on,
>   Se faire Loup.

serait que ***notre cher*** indique que le renard parle au nom d'un groupe, sous entendant que lui et le loup font partie de la même communauté. Ce nous inclusif signifierait alors :

> *Tu es des nôtres, je suis des tiens*.

Une source allant dans le même sens :

[image]

Marcel Gutwirth, *Un merveilleux sans éclat : La Fontaine ou la poésie exilée*, 1987

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Pas nécessairement en contradiction avec elle. La Fontaine a très bien pu jouer sur les deux sens, les associer.</sub>

Comment: +1 car, à l'appui de ta lecture (qui n'est pourtant toujours pas la mienne) on peut lire plus bas une 1ps explicite (***J**'approche des maisons*) au lieu d'un *nous approchons* pour rester conséquent.

Comment: Pourquoi pas:: Notre cher [ami], dans le sens que le renard appartient à un groupe? Les renards et les loups, ça ne fait pas deux. Autrement dit, " vous les loups " sont " nos chers " [amis], sarcasme. –

Comment: @sinopleincandescent Pourquoi en anglais? Je suis parfaitement capable de l'écrire en français...mais il parait que vous avez déjá fait votre choix.

Answer (score 1):

[ni locuteur natif ; ni spécialiste]

Je crois que c'est un cas appartenant au dit "nous de majesté" (voir ici : [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nous_de_majesté](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nous_de_majest%C3%A9))

LE LION MALADE ET LE RENARD

```
        Que Sa Majesté nous dispense :
        Grand merci de son passeport.
        Je le crois bon; mais dans cet antre
        Je vois fort bien comme l'on entre,
        Et ne vois pas comme on en sort.
```

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nous_de_majest%C3%A9

> nous de majesté m (uncountable)
>
> royal we, majestic plural (plural used by a sovereign)  Nous, Lion,
>   Roi des Animaux, décrétons : Afin que la paix règne parmi tous nos
>   sujets, il sera désormais expressément défendu de se manger les uns
>   les autres. (We, Lion, king of the beasts, decree: so that peace may
>   reign, our subjects are forbidden to eat each other.) (The Tale of the
>   Fox, 1930)

NB

Voir aussi les commentaires de @aCOSwt

> Le renard est ici (contrairement à l'autre fable) le Duc de Bourgogne.
>   (cf haut de page droite du lien de l'OP) (qui ne crachait pas sur le
>   nous de majesté)

and

> On a encore une confirmation en toute fin : "Prince, ma Muse tient
>   tout entier ce projet : Vous m'avez donné le sujet, Le dialogue, et la
>   morale."

Comment: L'expression « notre cher » n'apparait pas dans cette fable, ni associée à l'être qui a le titre de majesté (le lion), ni même dissociée de celui-ci. Le texte de cette fable n'est donc pas une preuve que le titre entraine l'appellation « notre cher ». En plus de cela, dans la fable du renard et du loup il n'est pas question de la majesté du loup, les deux caractères se tutoient, et jamais dans la littérature du passé on n'a trouvé  un cas où quelqu'un avec le titre de majesté aura été tutoyé.

Comment: Je suis assez d'accord avec LPH, le mélange à quelques lignes d'intervalle d'un "nous de majesté" et du tutoiement est étrange. Je ne vois par contre pas de meilleur explication, mais je dois bien avouer que la lecture des fables de La Fontaine n'est pas un exercice anodin pour moi non plus, même natif...

Comment: Autre remarque, selon moi l'exemple du "lion malade et le renard" n'est pas représentatif: je pense que le "nous" est ici bien la 1ière  personne du pluriel, mais peut-être que j'interprète mal la fable...

Comment: @LPH serait-il mieux que j'efface la réponse ?

Comment: @Dimitris > Que ce soit pour la validation des réponses à l'une de tes questions ou la suppression de l'une de tes réponses, je ne me précipiterais pas. A l'heure actuelle il n'y a que 2 intervenants sur ta réponse donc sa suppression me paraît prématurée même si LPH et moi semblons du même avis.

Comment: +1 Dim! Le renard est ici (contrairement à l'autre fable) le Duc de Bourgogne. (cf haut de page droite du lien de l'OP) (qui ne crachait pas sur le nous de majesté)

Comment: @aCOSwt Je te remercie pour la clarification.

Comment: On a encore une confirmation en toute fin : "***Prince**, ma Muse tient tout entier ce projet : Vous m'avez donné le sujet, Le dialogue, et la morale.*"

Comment: Bien c'est qu'un pronom personnel diffère d'un adjectif possessif, le premier est le sujet du verbe alors que le deuxième renseigne sur la relation qu'on a avec le sujet qui accomplit l'action (_à moi, à nous_). Mais la formulation pourrait renvoyer à un nous de majesté implicite. Mais le contexte justifie-t-il ça ? Pourquoi le renard voudrait-il dans un contexte où il veut se faire enseigner quelque chose du loup, implicitement référer à lui-même avec le nous de majesté ? Et finalement ne serait-ce pas plutôt un nous de modestie ??

Answer (score 1):

À titre de complément, on peut aussi observer que l'emploi de *notre* permet d'avoir l'alexandrin. D'autre part, ça m'a fait penser que dans la prière chrétienne [*Notre Père*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre_P%C3%A8re) on trouve aussi ce prototype pluriel (*Notre Père...*) singulier (*ton nom...*, quoique aussi *votre* mais ce n'est [pas directement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre_P%C3%A8re#Les_versions_liturgiques) un phénomène linguistique ; par ailleurs pas d'adjectif au singulier avec [*Je vous salue Marie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_vous_salue_Marie)) autrement que dans le contexte de la familiarité (*Père/Marie, cher*) ; qui sait si de La Fontaine ne s'appuie sur le tour pour y connoter flatterie ou « soumission », thèmes familiers chez cette créature. Ailleurs en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40047/le-renard-dit-au-loup-notre-cher-pourquoi#comment80082_40058) on a évoqué le sous-groupe et l'ellipse présumée du nom « ami », une variation intéressante sur un thème étayé dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40058). Similairement, personnellement j'interprète ici l'emploi de l'adjectif possessif au pluriel comme une forme de *déférence* envers l'auditoire permettant de centrer l'attention de tous sur le sujet, dans une fable où le narrateur s'était exprimé très directement tout juste avant, de surcroît à quelqu'un d'autre qui fait partie de l'auditoire à qui l'on propose cette histoire...